# How to set table data into multiple pages javascript html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't seem to find any information on how to generate multiple pages for tables with large amounts of data. Based on the user's filters the data generated into the table can be 1000+ rows. I am trying to find a way to have 50 rows per page and have arrow buttons to move to the next page ect.. Can someone point to some resources I can follow? Thank you.

Comment: How are you receiving the data you wish to filter? From a database/file/third-party --- API? Please provide details of how you get this data and the format you get it along with your attempt to filter it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As rightly said by @bronkula , you can achieve this by Pagination.
I would like to share some simple examples for reference:

Example:
Reference: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
"pagingType": "full_numbers"
} );
} );
```

JS Fiddle link for another example:
http://jsfiddle.net/LiquidSky/djav37tg/

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need thousands of rows, you can do a simple client side which takes almost no time at all. Here is a codepen example of that: https://codepen.io/ScottFSchmidt/pen/eMzdpO

However, for using a large amount of data (thousands?), you'll need to do a sever-side. This link has the basic HTML and server.php file(very important).https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html Make sure to also add the ssp.class.php file too which is this link: https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php

```
<?php

/*
 * DataTables example server-side processing script.
 *
 * Please note that this script is intentionally extremely simply to show how
 * server-side processing can be implemented, and probably shouldn't be used as
 * the basis for a large complex system. It is suitable for simple use cases as
 * for learning.
 *
 * See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server-
 * side processing requirements of DataTables.
 *
 * @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit
 */

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Easy set variables
 */

// DB table to use
$table = 'datatables_demo';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'first_name', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'last_name',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'position',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'office',     'dt' => 3 ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'start_date',
        'dt'        => 4,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return date( 'jS M y', strtotime($d));
        }
    ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'salary',
        'dt'        => 5,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return '$'.number_format($d);
        }
    )
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => '',
    'pass' => '',
    'db'   => '',
    'host' => ''
);


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

This should get you started.

Answer (score -1):

The concept you're looking for is **pagination**.

Designing pagination is one thing, coding it another. You might want to look into [pagination.js](http://pagination.js.org/)

Comment: Please read [answer]. Avoid answering [off-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and avoid providing link-only answers. Your answer is opinionated in providing a particular pagination solution which might or might not work with what OP has, especially since pagination is usually generated by the data provider. In all fairness, this question is way too broad, shows no research effort and is not useful. It therefore should not have been answered, and asking such questions should be discouraged.